# Nginx time out and errors

Tags: php, nginx, memcached

I am using Nginx with php-fpm and memcached, my nginx was working perfectly before and I was not using sessions in my script 10 days ago i updated my script and started to use session, for session i used memcache, but after this update my nginx and php-fpm are giving lot of error. My website is running on cloud server which have 2 core cpu and 2gb RAM and have average of ~480 concurrent users on website.
After installation of memcached my cpu usage is increased 10%.

Since two days i got 95 of these errors in my php-fpm error log.

```
[19-Aug-2015 22:33:05] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 4 idle, and 49 total children
[19-Aug-2015 22:33:06] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (50), consider raising it
[20-Aug-2015 01:32:37] WARNING: [pool www] child 14293 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 36091.050170 seconds from start
[20-Aug-2015 01:32:37] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19144 started
```

In nginx error log i am getting these errors.

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

This is my Nginx configuration;

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  off;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

And this is Memcached configuration,

```
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="5024"
CACHESIZE="100"
OPTIONS=""
```

please tell What is the problem in this ? and how can i solve it.

Comment: In Nginx header functions not working properly, header function is use to get header information which content session id.